# How to handle different configurations for each module using Nestjs Config

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, nestjs-config

I want to have different config for each module like specified [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#partial-registration)

But I am not able to achieve this, here is the issue that I am facing:
https://github.com/nestjs/config/issues/947

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand why you need such behaviour, and maybe with more information I could give you a more detailed input. However, from the information you provided, I would suggest to keep the configuration variables globally scoped and avoid name collisions, not only for design purposes but for readability also.
If you have a lot of configuration variables, you can always separate them into different JSON files and load them from each module, but naming them differently.
Let me know if this is a viable solution for your problem.

Comment: I want to do database seeding in microservices. Every service has same json object for the database configurations so it is not applicable for me. 

PS: I am using Nestjs workspaces for monorepo